# Do I need JDK & JRE in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk, jre

In Windows 7 I had to install jdk & jre to program with eclipse. In the software center I can only find OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime. Do I need both to program in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Open up your terminal and type:

java -version

You will have to install it if your program is not found. Take a look at these instructions:

[How to Install Oracle Java JRE on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JRE-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Comment: If I want both for my system will I be ok with installing OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way for beginners is to install oracle JDK via a PPA : http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Just three lines, copy-pasted will give you the desired functionality